# How can I accomplish parallel processing in R?

Tags: multithreading

If I have two datasets (having equal number of rows and columns) and I wish to run a piece of code that I have made, then there are two options obviously, either to go with sequential execution or parallel programming.

Now, the algorithm (code) that I have made is a big one and consists of multiple for loops. I wish to ask, is there any way to directly use it on both of them or will I have to transform the code in some way? A heads up would be great.

Comment: Can you please add (samples of) your data sets?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: you do not have to transform the code to run it on two datasets in parallel, it should work fine like it is.

The need for parallel processing usually arises in two ways (for most users, I would imagine):

1. You have code you can run sequentially, but you would like to do it in parallel.
2. You have a function that is taking very long to execute on a large dataset, and you would like to run it in parallel to speed it up.

For the first case, you do not have to do anything, you can just execute it in parallel using one of the libraries designed for it, or just run two instances of R on the same computer and run the same code but with different datasets in each of them. 
It doesn't matter how many for loops you have in there and you don't even need to have the same number of rows in columns in the datasets.
If it runs fine sequentially, it means there will be no dependence between the parallel chains and thus no problem.
Since your question falls in the first case, you can run it in parallel.

If you have the second case, you can sometimes turn it into the first case by splitting your dataset into pieces (where you can run each of the pieces sequentially) and then you run it in parallel. This is easier said than done, and won't always be possible. It is also why not all functions just have a `run.in.parallel=TRUE` option: it is not always obvious how you should split the data, nor is it always possible.

So you have already done most of the work by writing the functions, and splitting the data.
Here is a general way of doing parallel processing with one function, on two datasets:

```r
library( doParallel )
cl <- makeCluster( 2 ) # for 2 processors, i.e. 2 parallel chains
registerDoParallel( cl )

datalist <- list(mydataset1 , mydataset2)

# now start the chains
nchains <- 2 # for two processors

results_list <- foreach(i=1:nchains , 
                .packages = c( 'packages_you_need') ) %dopar% {
     result <- find.string( datalist[[i]] )
     return(result) }
```

The result will be a list with two elements, each containing the results from a chain. You can then combine it as you wish, or use a `.combine` function. See the `foreach` help for details.

You can use this code any time you have a case like number 1 described above. Most of the time you can also use it for cases like number 2, if you spend some time thinking about how you want to divide the data, and then combine the results. Think of it as a "parallel wrapper". 
It should work in Windows, GNU/Linux, and Mac OS, but I haven't tested it on all of them.

I keep this script handy whenever I need a quick speed-up, but I still always start out by writing code I can run sequentially. Thinking in parallel hurts my brain.

Comment: thanks for input. But, will this run directly or will I have to modify  my original function too for parallel processing?

Comment: It should run directly. If you only want the function to run on two datasets, in parallel, there is no need to alter it. Think of it like running two instances of R in parallel. You don't need to alter the function for that. If you want a function that would automatically run in parallel, given one dataset, that's a different story. You then need to tell the function how to split the dataset, etc.  Your case is simple. You have one function and you want to run it twice. So no need to change it.

Comment: I will update my answer to clarify that, I see I didn't answer your whole question!

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks a lot for the help. I had only one more doubt. I omitted the `.packages` argument from the `foreach` function and I tried executing my code using the code snippet that you supplied using two simple strings and not an entire dataset. Now, it worked, but is there any way I can test whether it worked using parallel processing or a normal sequential execution took place?

Comment: Short answer: if you didn't get any warnings, it probably worked! With two simple strings, they are likely to execute so fast that you won't be able to see if they ran in parallel. If you are on windows, you could open the task manager and see how much of your processing powers are being used on two big datasets (I don't know exactly how to do this). On Linux, I use the `htop` utility on the command line to see whether processes are really running in parallel (it shows you how much each process is taking).

Comment: I am using Mac OsX. Any special feature in that too I can use?

Comment: I think htop may work on a mac, but I am not sure. I think this is the perfect topic for a new question, though :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69511/discussion-between-dwcoder-and-qirohchan).

Comment: this seems to work perfectly fine if I make the list of two simple strings, for example, `datalist <- c("abcabcabc","adcadcadc")` but if the datalist consists of two datasets, each containing multiple rows, then this code gives the error, `Error in { : task 1 failed - "'to' must be of length 1"`. Any help? Thanks!