# Parallel processing for 2 datasets

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing

This is basically a followup to this question that I previously asked. 
The link is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115272/how-can-i-accomplish-parallel-processing-in-r
```

Now, the code, that is:

```
library( doParallel )
cl <- makeCluster( 2 ) # for 2 processors, i.e. 2 parallel chains
registerDoParallel( cl )

datalist <- list(mydataset1 , mydataset2)

# now start the chains
nchains <- 2 # for two processors

results_list <- foreach(i=1:nchains , 
                .packages = c( 'packages_you_need') ) %dopar% {
     result <- find.string( datalist[[i]] )
     return(result) }
```

This seems to work perfectly fine when the `datalist` contains 2 simple strings, that is, for example,

```
datalist <- list("abcabcabc","adcadcadc")
```

But, if I merge two actual datasets each containing multiple rows of strings, for example,

```
Dataset1:

abcabcabc
adcadcadc
aecaecaec
afcafcafc
.........

Dataset2:

xyzxyzxyz
xzcxzcxzc
xtcxtcxtc
xdcxdcxdc
.........
```

If I have datasets like these, then this produces an error which is:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "'to' must be of length 1"
```

Any suggestions as to why this must be happening or how can I remove this?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
str(datalist) - List of 2
 $ : chr [1:3631] "000000000fbff000ff0000f00000" "000000000000fffffffffff0f000" "bb0bb00000f000000000bfff0000" "00b0b000bfbffffbffbf0ff00000" ...
 $ : chr [1:3631] "000000000srst000tt0000t00000" "000000000000ttttttttttt0r000" "ss0tt00000q000000000sstt0000" "00s0q000ssqtsstrstss0ss00000" ...


dput(head(datalist))

"00000000r0t0st0000p000000000", "00000ssssttstssttts000000000", 
"000000000r00sq000tp000000000", "0000000000tsq0sq0qt000000000", 
"000q0000r00000000rss00000000", "00000000ttttttttttt000000000", 
"0000000000s0qs000s0000000000", "000000ppqppqsrrrsr0000000000", 
"00000r00s0t00ss00st000000000", "0000000000s000s0tt0000000000", 
"00000s0000ttstq000t000000000", "0000000000qrs0t0s00t00000000", 
"000000000s000stt0t0000000000", "0000000000qtr0000t0000000000", 
"0000000000rrsrsqrr0000000000", "0000000000tsp0s000s000000000", 
 ..............................................................
```

Edit2: An example of 4 elements in each dataset.

```
str(datalist)

List of 2
 $ : chr [1:4] "000000000fbff000ff0000f00000" "000000000000fffffffffff0f000" "bb0bb00000f000000000bfff0000" "00b0b000bfbffffbffbf0ff00000"
 $ : chr [1:4] "000000000srst000tt0000t00000" "000000000000ttttttttttt0r000" "ss0tt00000q000000000sstt0000" "00s0q000ssqtsstrstss0ss00000"


 dput(head(datalist))
list(c("000000000fbff000ff0000f00000", "000000000000fffffffffff0f000", 
"bb0bb00000f000000000bfff0000", "00b0b000bfbffffbffbf0ff00000"
), c("000000000srst000tt0000t00000", "000000000000ttttttttttt0r000", 
"ss0tt00000q000000000sstt0000", "00s0q000ssqtsstrstss0ss00000"
))
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the results of `str(datalist)` and  `dput(head(datalist))` in?  That will make it much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I have done that. :)

Comment: Don't truncate the `dput` - I'm going to copy it and use it for testing so I need the whole thing.

Comment: I wouldn't have done that but it contains around 3631 rows which are difficult to attach here.

Comment: `dput(head(datalist))` will only give a few lines of each part, that's the function of `head`.  But if you mean there are 3631 list elements, please subset it to maybe 3-4 elements and then `dput(head...))`.  Thanks. UPDATE: you don't need to subset, I see the elements themselves are 3631 long.

Comment: Alright, I will do that. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73517/discussion-between-qirohchan-and-bryan-hanson).

Comment: In case you left the chat, try using the parallel code with `unlist(datalist[[i]])`, that will be a character vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one working example using your data structure.  I've used `grep` instead of your `find.string` for simplicity and testing.  Added a `.combine` argument and also assigned the value of the `foreach` operation (a mistake I was making last week when @SteveWesson helped me out).  By the way, you need to change `%do%` to `%dopar%` when you have longer data.  The parallel operations won't kick in until you have longer vectors in my experience.  It's not exactly what you want to do, but hopefully you can work from here.

```
library( doParallel )
cl <- makeCluster( 2 ) # for 2 processors, i.e. 2 parallel chains
registerDoParallel( cl )

datalist <- list(c("000000000fbff000ff0000f00000", "000000000000fffffffffff0f000", 
"bb0bb00000f000000000bfff0000", "00b0b000bfbffffbffbf0ff00000"
), c("000000000srst000tt0000t00000", "000000000000ttttttttttt0r000", 
"ss0tt00000q000000000sstt0000", "00s0q000ssqtsstrstss0ss00000"
))

nchains <- 2 # for two processors

out <- results_list <- foreach(i=1:nchains, .combine = c) %do% {
     result <- grep("ff|tt", unlist(datalist[[i]]))
     print(result)
     return(result) }
out # shows result too
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried tweaking `grep` to `find.string()` in my case which accepts a character vector but it doesn't seem to work. I end up with the same error messages which are: 
`Error in { : task 1 failed - "'to' must be of length 1"
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In len:1 : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
2: In len:1 : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
3`.

Comment: Alright, I guess edit your original question to include `find.string` and we'll take a look.  Please play with it a little to make `find.string` as short as necessary to cause the error.